# Subinacl Access Denied using subkeyreg

Tags: windows-7, ownership

I have windows 7 x86, I am the only user and Administrator of my pc.
I want to be able to take ownership of the key(below)  but subinacl will not allow it.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR
>
> The error is: RegSetKeySecurity Error: 5 Access is denied.

I've tried to launch it with an elevated command line and it still says error 5.

Two question:
Why is it doing this?
How to take ownership of this key? I would like to use subinacl if possible. But I am open minded to other tools as long as they can be used from the command line.

Comment: Why do you need to take ownership of that key?

Comment: @Randolph West I want to delete every subkey within it but it won't let me. Besides, I want to know why it doesn't work. It works  if set the permissions manually from regedit.

Comment: @AlexanderCeed, did you run `subinacl` from an admin command-prompt?

Comment: @Synetech Yes. I right click on cmd.exe and select "Run as admin"

Answer (score 0):

You have to take ownership of the registry key before you can change its permissions (you should set the ownership back afterwards).

Hmm, I could have sworn you can use the [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc753024.aspx) command to take ownership of a registry key, but it looks like you can’t.

Instead, depending on the version of Windows you use you can use the [`cacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872) command, [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29), or [`xcalcs`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) (update with a [VB script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825751)), or even a third-party tool like [RegDACL](http://www.heysoft.de/old/RegDACLe.htm).

(`cacls` and `icacls` come with Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Use the commands below with [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/) with administrative privileges:

```
set X="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR"
SetACL.exe -on %X% -ot reg -rec cont_obj -actn setowner -ownr "n:Everyone"
SetACL.exe -on %X% -ot reg -rec cont_obj -actn ace -ace "n:Everyone;p:full"
```